# Passing nested objects from React frontend to backend

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to pass a series of nested objects from React to Ruby on Rails. Here's an object example:

```
{
  library: "favorite",
  movie: {
    name: "James Bond Skyfall",
    year: "2012",
    screenshots: [file1, file2],
  },
}
```

An obvious solution is to stringify the object, pass it as a param and parse it on the Rails side. However this is quite cumbersome, and I'm looking for something easier and more intuitive.

Comment: That's quite the de-facto way to do it. How much simpler do you expect it to be? Send it via HTTP request, handle on BE side.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I found so far is to use `FormData`, for example:

```
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append("library", "favorite")
formData.append("movie[name]", "James Bond Skyfall")
formData.append("movie[year]", "2012")

formData.append("movie[screenshots][]", file1)
formData.append("movie[screenshots][]", file2)
```

This [GitHub thread](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/92) was very helpful